# pandas: skip strings when loading a csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database of interest rates whose entries occasionally are strings like "NA"s, is it possible to skip those rows by type (all the strings)?

[EDIT]
http://www.banque-france.fr/fileadmin/user_upload/banque_de_france/Economie_et_Statistiques/Changes_et_Taux/en/qs.d.ieutio1m.csv

```
04/19/2000;3.824

04/20/2000;3.834

04/21/2000;ND

04/24/2000;ND

04/25/2000;3.881

04/26/2000;3.927
```

I am loading it (after having saved and deleted the initial comments) very simply by

```
pd.io.parsers.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="/mypath.csv")
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code and how you load it in? Also, if possible, some examples of the DB (is it CSV or SQL or what?)

Comment: You could add "NA" as an identifier for NaN values and drop them afterwards if you don't have too many NaN values

Comment: True! Just to make sure...is it possible to skip by type? I mean, there are less "clean" databases out there, and checking all the lines for identifiers would be pretty painful

ps thx, I didn't think to that ;)

Comment: Not that I can think of but parsing row by row will be slow, it'd be better to just read it all in and drop afterwards unless you expect a lot of NaN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dropna` in combination with the `na_values` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv('qs.d.ieutio1m.csv', sep=';', header=4, na_values=['ND'])
df = df.dropna()
```

or more simply:

```
df = pd.read_csv('qs.d.ieutio1m.csv', sep=';', header=4, na_values=['ND']).dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do as @EdChum suggested above:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/mypath.csv", na_values = ['ND'], sep = ';')
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

This should read in all `ND` values as `NaN`s and then you can drop them in-place immediately. You can also have different `NaN` values if you need, e.g. `['ND', 'nd']`.

The strings specified by `na_values` are appended to the default `NaN` values in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) unless `keep_default_na` option is adjusted accordingly.